# Вывод текста

Tags: wpf

Нужно вывести отформатированный текст в окне (WPF). Пытаюсь сделать с помощью textblock, не выходит. Текст объемом более примерно 1000 знаков.

Comment: А можно поподробнее - что именно не выходит? У меня проблем с выводом форматированного текста в TextBlock никогда не возникало, но были ситуации когда забывал поставить свойство переноса на другую строку.

Answer (score 1):

Используй [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx).